# How can I remove or make null a navigation property before updating a record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Here is a simplistic explanation of my object model:

```
class Document
{
     public int ID;
     public List<DocumentActivity> Activities;
}

class DocumentActivity
{
     public int ID;
     [ForeignKey("User")]
     public int UserID;
     public User User;
}

class User
{
     public int ID;
     public List<DocumentActivity> Activities;
}
```

I am building a Web API with desktop client.  I have a Document object on the client which contains 1 new DocumentActivity, which references a User (which then in turn has many associated DocumentActivities.  When I update the Document, I want to just update the Document with the DocumentActivity with the UserID reference, but I don't want to mark each DocumentActivity of the referenced user "unchanged" because this is slow so I want to "clean" the Document object before updating to only include what I want.

I'm thinking I can somehow clone the object and modify it to suit my needs but this seems like a lot of work.  And my one attempt to just make the User "null" didn't work as anticipated.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make the foreign key nullable by:

```
public int? UserId { get; set; }
```

And then instead of making User null, you can just make UserId null.

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem.   What I'm trying to do is get rid of the expensive User property so I don't need to deal with it on the server.